# How to find the oldest date in an SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle, express, oracle-apex

I'm making a SQL query and I need some help

**The question is:**
What is an employee's current salary , and what was their salary when they first started working?
(give name , first letters , current salary , department name , start date and their salary when they started)

**The problem is:**
I keep getting all the dates, and I can't find out how to filter it to only the first date (start/hire date) being shown.
Any suggestions?
My SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT M.NAME,
       M.FIRSTLETTERS,
       M.MONTHSALARY,
       D.NAME,
       H.STARTDATE,
       H.SALARY
FROM   E_EMPLOYEES M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN E_DEPARTMENTS A
                    ON M.AFD = A.ANR
       INNER JOIN E_historie H
               ON M.MNR = H.MNR
```

Comment: Sorry , but I'm really new to SQL, are there any more simple solutions for this query? Thanks for replying regardless !

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `keep` for this purpose.  The query looks like:

```
SELECT M.NAME, M.FIRSTLETTERS,
       MIN(H.STARTDATE) as STARTDATE, 
       MAX(H.SALARY) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.STARTDATE) as FIRST_SALARY,
       MAX(H.SALARY) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.STARTDATE DESC) as LAST_SALARY
FROM E_EMPLOYEES M INNER JOIN
     E_DEPARTMENTS A
     ON M.AFD = A.ANR INNER JOIN
     E_historie H
     ON M.MNR = H.MNR 
GROUP BY M.MNR, M.NAME, M.FIRSTLETTERS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the first salary of each employee from history table

```
SELECT M.NAME,
       M.FIRSTLETTERS,
       M.MONTHSALARY, -- considering this is current salary
       A.NAME, -- I think there is a typo here Alias name should be A not H
       H.STARTDATE,
       H.SALARY
FROM   E_EMPLOYEES M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN E_DEPARTMENTS A
                    ON M.AFD = A.ANR
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY H.MNR ORDER BY H.STARTDATE ASC) AS Rn,
                          H.MNR,
                          H.STARTDATE,
                          H.STARTDATE
                   FROM   E_historie H) H
               ON M.MNR = H.MNR
WHERE  Rn = 1
```

Comment: I like the approach but... where `D.NAME` come from?